# Using Laravel whenLoaded() deeper than one level

Tags: php, laravel

How do I use [whenLoaded()](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Resources/ConditionallyLoadsAttributes.html#method_whenLoaded) for deeper than one level relations? It seems as if one can only use `whenLoaded` with the first relation depth like this:

```
'season' => $this->whenLoaded('origin', function () {
    return new SeasonResource($this->origin->season);
}),
```

But then Laravel, if `origin` is loaded, but not `season`, Laravel will load it, which creates an N+1 problem. Both `origin` and `season` relationships are conditional, and not always used. Therefor I want to use something like this:

```
$this->whenLoaded('origin.season', ...)
```

or this:

```
'season' => $this->whenLoaded('origin', function () {
     return new SeasonResource($this->origin->whenLoaded('season'));
}),
```

Neither of these work. I suppose the deeper relations are not stored on the model itself, and in the second case, `whenLoaded()` does not exists on the query builder.

> How do I use [whenLoaded()](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Resources/ConditionallyLoadsAttributes.html#method_whenLoaded) for deeper than one level relations?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe the reason this is not implemented is because it only makes sense for `hasOne` and `belongsTo` relationships (relationships that return an object, not a collection).

But if that is the case for you, you could do this:

```
'season' => $this->when(
    $this->relationLoaded('origin') &&
    $this->origin->relationLoaded('season'),
    function () {
        return new SeasonResource($this->origin->season);
    }
),
```

Basically, use `->when` instead of `->whenLoaded` and manually check if the relation is loaded using the `->relationLoaded` public method on the model.

Comment: Do you have any idea if it was originS? I mean a many to many relation

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this and looking for many to many relationships, I've found a solution.

Let's say you've something like

```
User ---> user_lived_cities ----> city
```

with table structures as

`user_lived_cities`
`user_id` | `city_id`
------ | ------

`cities`
`id` | `name`
------ | ------

You want to load the cities the user lived in with something like

```
User::with('livedCities.city')->take(n)->get();
```

In the resource, you can manipulate the values like this

```
    $livedCityRelation = $this->whenLoaded('livedCities');
    $livedCities = $this->when(!empty((array)$livedCityRelation), function () use ($livedCityRelation) {
        if ($livedCityRelation instanceof MissingValue) return []; // the relation has no value
        $relationLoaded = count($livedCityRelation) /* Remember: It's a collection */ && $livedCityRelation[0]->relationLoaded('city');
        return $relationLoaded ? $livedCityRelation->pluck('city') : []; // you can manipulate as per you need. I'm just extracting the city relation from here
    });
```

In your resource in `toArray` method, you can return

```
return [
    ...,
    'lived_cities' => City::collection($livedCities),
];
```

Remember, `$livedCities` is basically a collection at this point and you can manipulate it as you wish.
If I want to just return an array of city names, I can do that as well with this

```
$livedCities->pluck('name')
```

You can apply any [collection method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods) that you want to manipulate as per your wish.

Don't forget to import this at the top

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\MissingValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for each nested relationship in turn. For example:

```
$postsLoaded = $user->relationLoaded('posts');
$commentsLoaded = $user->posts->first()->relationLoaded('comments');
$likesLoaded = $user->posts->first()->comments->first()->relationLoaded('likes');
```

This isn't my solution but it solved my problem - posting so it may help others as this was hard to find. All credit goes to SaeedPrez:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/this-relationloaded-for-distant-relationships

Answer (score 0):

## For Laravel 10.x

```
Model::with(`level1.level2`)
```

#### Also works with arrays for multiple `whenLoaded` relationships

```
Model::with(
   [
      'level1'=>['sub1','sub2']
   ]
)
```